# CSS align elements along borders, not a base line or top

Tags: css

Is there a way to achieve an alignment like Google Keep's notes with pure CSS? I have tried `display: inline(-block);` but the only possible alignments are `top, bottom, baseline` and `middle` in some cases. Also `display: flex;` and some extra properties give me a better distribution on my elements but they're still aligning on a straight line. I can only think of a solution with JavaScript and I've wasted hours with googling but I can't find anything. Is there rather simple CSS approach for this?

**Edit:** This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9zot2bm/8/) shows how it currently looks, [this](http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/69657000/69657987/google-keep-04-700x437.jpg) is how I want it to look.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Check the latest edit :)

Comment: Here you go: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Comment: @Mr Lister tried this without success..

Comment: @Ferrrmolina You are my hero, send me your iban and i will donate :)

Comment: @NiklasVest ever seen **[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)**?

Comment: @AGE Thanks for the link, I appreciate it but I don't like using external dependencies and I asked for a CSS aproach :)

Comment: Also check these sources to understand how the properties you will use work. http://pastebin.com/1aEwEXK0

Comment: @NiklasVest Sorry, I'm not too fluent in flex boxes, but here: https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/j9zot2bm/9/

Comment: @MrLister Thanks I have thought about a column layout but I will sort my divs alphabetically and that would not quite work with columns, still thanks for the efforts!

Comment: @Ferrrmolina Thanks, I would gladly accept your comment as answer but thats not possible :) have a upvote though!

Comment: I put an answer if you want to accept this, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on [this pen](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout), you can do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item color--lightblue"></div>
  <div class="item color--sblue"></div>
  <div class="item color--blue"></div>
  <div class="item color--darkblue"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 2;
}

.item {
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 230px;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 250px;
}
.item:nth-child(n+1) {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
/* Only for demo */
.color--sblue {
  background: steelblue;
}
.color--blue {
  background: blue;
}
.color--lightblue {
  background: lightblue;
}
.color--darkblue {
  background: darkblue;
}
```

**[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/j9zot2bm/12/)**

This 3 properties make the magic:

**column-count:** http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp

**column-gap:** http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-gap.asp

**column-fill:** http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-fill.asp

Comment: I just noticed that the solution still doesn't fit my needs since it is similar to @Mr Lister's comment on my post, going to accept regardless though.

Comment: I edited my answer again, with more efficient code. The problem is that if you use float, there can be aligned for obvious reasons. With FlexBox would be very difficult, and inline-block is about the same as with float. So I would not know how else to do it, honestly.

Comment: Ferrrmolina I will try it the next couple of days though I will probably end up using @Mr List flexbox approach. Thanks you both.